Can't get velocity bridging navsat plugin to ROS2 Humble
Although I can see the position (latitude, longitude, altitude) and ENU velocity in Gazebo Garden, I can't bridge them to ROS 2. I can only see position measurements but I need both, how can I solve this?
I've checked the ros_gz_bridge readme and the message gz.msgs.NavSat is linked to gps_msgs/msg/GPSFix in ROS, but also with sensor_msgs/msg/NavSatFix.
When I try to make a bridge using the GPSFix message I get an error.
I'm using ROS2 Humble and Gazebo Garden on Ubuntu 22.04.
